# Stored procedure with datetime condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have created a table with the following set of data

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RiskTable]
(
    [ReqID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ModuleName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [AssociatedRisk] [nvarchar](50) NULL
)
```

| Model | AssociatedRisk | Created Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| IDP | High | 2022-12-18 00:00:00.0000000 |
| Saa | High | 2023-01-02 00:00:00.0000000 |
| Saa | Medium | 2023-01-07 00:00:00.0000000 |
| Saa | Critical | 2023-01-29 00:00:00.0000000 |
| Saa | Low | 2023-02-05 00:00:00.0000000 |
| Saa | Low | 2023-02-07 00:00:00.0000000 |
| EEE | Critical | 2023-03-09 00:00:00.0000000 |
| Info | Low | 2023-04-08 00:00:00.0000000 |
| IDP | High | 2023-04-28 00:00:00.0000000 |
| IDP | Medium | 2023-05-08 00:00:00.0000000 |

I have a stored procedure that satisfies the following condition:

1. If I'm giving model = saa, start_date = 2023-01-01, end_date = 2023-02-10, I want it to show me the total number of risks (low, Medium, High, and Critical) of those particular months (2023-01-01(Jan), 2023-02-10(Feb)) of the model 'saa'.
2. If I'm giving model = Null, start_date = 2023-04-01, end_date = 2023-05-11, I want it to show me the total number of risks (low, Medium, High, and Critical) of those particular months (2023-04-01(Apr), 2023-05-11(May)) of all the models.
   output I'm getting for my previous condition:
   | Model | Month    | Risk   |  Total no. of risk|
   |------ |--------- |------- |------------------ |
   |All    |Apr or 04 |Low     | 1                 |
   |All    |Apr or 04 |Medium  | 0                 |
   |All    |Apr or 04 |High    | 1                 |
   |All    |Apr or 04 |Critical| 0                 |
   |All    |May or 05 |Low     | 0                 |
   |All    |May or 05 |Medium  | 1                 |
   |All    |May or 05 |High    | 0                 |
   |All    |May or 05 |Critical| 0                 |

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE Month_base_global
                @model varchar(20),   
                @start_date date,
                @end_date date
    AS
    BEGIN
    IF @model = 'ALL'
        BEGIN
          SELECT 'ALL' as [Module], ac.[Month], ac.AssociatedRisk as Risk, count(ri.ModuleName) as   'Total risks'
        FROM (
          SELECT DISTINCT convert(varchar(7), r.CreatedDate, 126) as [month], a.AssociatedRisk,  m.ModuleName
          FROM RiskTable r
          FULL OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT DISTINCT AssociatedRisk
            FROM RiskTable
          ) as a on a.AssociatedRisk is not null
          FULL OUTER JOIN (
             SELECT DISTINCT ModuleName
             FROM RiskTable
          ) as m on m.ModuleName is not null
          WHERE (r.CreatedDate) between (@start_date) and (@end_date) 
        ) as ac
        LEFT JOIN RiskTable ri on ac.[month] = convert(varchar(7), ri.CreatedDate, 126)
                               and ac.AssociatedRisk = ri.AssociatedRisk
                               and ac.ModuleName = ri.ModuleName
        GROUP BY ac.[month], ac.AssociatedRisk
        ORDER BY ac.[month], ac.AssociatedRisk desc
    END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
        SELECT @model as [Module], ac.[Month], ac.AssociatedRisk as Risk, count(ri.ModuleName) as 'Total risks'
        FROM (
          SELECT DISTINCT convert(varchar(7), r.CreatedDate, 126) as [month], a.AssociatedRisk, m.ModuleName
          FROM RiskTable r
          FULL OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT DISTINCT AssociatedRisk
            FROM RiskTable
          ) as a on a.AssociatedRisk is not null
          FULL OUTER JOIN (
             SELECT DISTINCT ModuleName
             FROM RiskTable
          ) as m on m.ModuleName = @model
            WHERE r.CreatedDate between DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, @start_date), 0) and eomonth(@end_date)
        ) as ac
        LEFT JOIN RiskTable ri on ac.[month] = convert(varchar(7), ri.CreatedDate, 126)
                               and ac.AssociatedRisk = ri.AssociatedRisk
                               and ac.ModuleName = ri.ModuleName
        GROUP BY ac.ModuleName, ac.[month], ac.AssociatedRisk
        ORDER BY ac.[month], ac.AssociatedRisk desc
    END
    END
    Exec Month_base_global 'ALL' , '2022-02-01', '2023-01-28'
```

Now I have few more condition
`Exec Month_base_global 'ALL' , null, '2023-01-28'`

3.If Model = ALL or any particular model like 'Saa' or 'IDA' or anything, then Start_date = null and end_date = 2023-01-28. It has to fetch all the records from the start in the table of that particular model or ALL.

`Exec Month_base_global 'ALL' , '2022-12-03', null`

4.If If Model = ALL or any particular model like 'Saa' or 'IDA' or anything, then Start_date = 2022-12-03 and end_date = null means it has to show the records from that particular start_date to the till date(uptodate).

`Exec Month_base_global 'ALL' , null, null`

5.If Model = ALL or any particular model like 'Saa' or 'IDA' or anything, start_date = null, end_date = null means it has to show all the records from the start of the createddate to the till date(uptodate).

can someone help me with this? Thanks

Comment: The way to get this kind of business logic working correctly is to work out and test individual queries before putting them in stored code.

Comment: If you have too many combinations of conditions, i would rewrite the procedure using dynamic sql, this way you just build your parts depending on the parameters. This usually means your "main" logic cannot differ too much, but it looks like you just want to skip some of the where:s depending on various parameters, which is perfect for dynamic SQL

Comment: @siggemannen Can you help me with this in dynamic Sql

Comment: I can't write your code for you, but it's pretty easy. you start with declare @sql nvarchar(max). Then you build it on by doing: if modelParam = 'all' -- append select 'all' to the variable, else append something else. Rince and repeat

Comment: You can read about some ideas here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/108593/stored-procedure-with-recompile/108669#108669 or https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by Initializing start date to a previous date, such as `'1970-01-01'` and end date to `'2030-12-31'` :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Month_base_global
                @model varchar(20),   
                @p_start_date date,
                @p_end_date date
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @start_date date;
DECLARE @end_date date;
    SET @start_date = @p_start_date ;
    SET @end_date = @p_end_date ;
    IF (@p_start_date IS NULL)
    BEGIN
       SET @start_date = '1970-01-01';
    END

    IF (@p_end_date IS NULL)
    BEGIN
       SET @end_date = '2030-12-31';
    END

    IF @model = 'ALL'
        BEGIN
          SELECT 'ALL' as [Module], ac.[Month], ac.AssociatedRisk as Risk, count(ri.ModuleName) as   'Total risks'
        FROM (
          SELECT DISTINCT convert(varchar(7), r.CreatedDate, 126) as [month], a.AssociatedRisk,  m.ModuleName
          FROM RiskTable r
          FULL OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT DISTINCT AssociatedRisk
            FROM RiskTable
          ) as a on a.AssociatedRisk is not null
          FULL OUTER JOIN (
             SELECT DISTINCT ModuleName
             FROM RiskTable
          ) as m on m.ModuleName is not null
          WHERE (r.CreatedDate) between (@start_date) and (@end_date) 
        ) as ac
        LEFT JOIN RiskTable ri on ac.[month] = convert(varchar(7), ri.CreatedDate, 126)
                               and ac.AssociatedRisk = ri.AssociatedRisk
                               and ac.ModuleName = ri.ModuleName
        GROUP BY ac.[month], ac.AssociatedRisk
        ORDER BY ac.[month], ac.AssociatedRisk desc
    END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
        SELECT @model as [Module], ac.[Month], ac.AssociatedRisk as Risk, count(ri.ModuleName) as 'Total risks'
        FROM (
          SELECT DISTINCT convert(varchar(7), r.CreatedDate, 126) as [month], a.AssociatedRisk, m.ModuleName
          FROM RiskTable r
          FULL OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT DISTINCT AssociatedRisk
            FROM RiskTable
          ) as a on a.AssociatedRisk is not null
          FULL OUTER JOIN (
             SELECT DISTINCT ModuleName
             FROM RiskTable
          ) as m on m.ModuleName = @model
            WHERE r.CreatedDate between DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, @start_date), 0) and eomonth(@end_date)
        ) as ac
        LEFT JOIN RiskTable ri on ac.[month] = convert(varchar(7), ri.CreatedDate, 126)
                               and ac.AssociatedRisk = ri.AssociatedRisk
                               and ac.ModuleName = ri.ModuleName
        GROUP BY ac.ModuleName, ac.[month], ac.AssociatedRisk
        ORDER BY ac.[month], ac.AssociatedRisk desc
    END
END
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/cY2QW-IP)

Comment: "You can accomplish this by Initializing start date to a previous date, such as '1970-01-01' and end date to '2030-12-31' " Instead of end_date = '2030-12-31'. Can end_date be changed into up to date like 'SysDateTime'

Comment: I changed it to SysDateTime. It works perfectly. Thank you so much Since i'm a beginner I learned a lot from you. Once again thanks

Answer (score 0):

By working on this you can update your stored procedure with conditions applied by code as mentioned:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Month_base_global
@model varchar(20),
@start_date date,
@end_date date
AS
BEGIN
IF @model = 'ALL' AND @start_date IS NOT NULL AND @end_date IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SELECT 'ALL' as [Module], ac.[Month], ac.AssociatedRisk as Risk, COUNT(ri.ModuleName) as 'Total risks'
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(varchar(7), r.CreatedDate, 126) as [month], a.AssociatedRisk, m.ModuleName
        FROM RiskTable r
        FULL OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT DISTINCT AssociatedRisk
            FROM RiskTable
        ) as a on a.AssociatedRisk IS NOT NULL
        FULL OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT DISTINCT ModuleName
            FROM RiskTable
        ) as m on m.ModuleName IS NOT NULL
        WHERE r.CreatedDate >= @start_date AND r.CreatedDate <= @end_date
    ) as ac
    LEFT JOIN RiskTable ri on ac.[month] = CONVERT(varchar(7), ri.CreatedDate, 126)
                           AND ac.AssociatedRisk = ri.AssociatedRisk
                           AND ac.ModuleName = ri.ModuleName
    GROUP BY ac.[month], ac.AssociatedRisk
    ORDER BY ac.[month], ac.AssociatedRisk DESC
END
ELSE IF @model = 'ALL' AND @start_date IS NULL AND @end_date IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SELECT 'ALL' as [Module], ac.[Month], ac.AssociatedRisk as Risk, COUNT(ri.ModuleName) as 'Total risks'
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(varchar(7), r.CreatedDate, 126) as [month], a.AssociatedRisk, m.ModuleName
        FROM RiskTable r
        FULL OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT DISTINCT AssociatedRisk
            FROM RiskTable
        ) as a on a.AssociatedRisk IS NOT NULL
        FULL OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT DISTINCT ModuleName
            FROM RiskTable
        ) as m on m.ModuleName IS NOT NULL
        WHERE r.CreatedDate <= @end_date
    ) as ac
    LEFT JOIN RiskTable ri on ac.[month] = CONVERT(varchar(7), ri.CreatedDate, 126)
                           AND ac.AssociatedRisk = ri.AssociatedRisk
                           AND ac.ModuleName = ri.ModuleName
    GROUP BY ac.[month], ac.AssociatedRisk
    ORDER BY ac.[month], ac.AssociatedRisk DESC
END
ELSE IF @model = 'ALL' AND @start_date IS NOT NULL AND @end_date IS NULL
BEGIN
    SELECT 'ALL' as [Module], ac.[Month], ac.AssociatedRisk as Risk, COUNT(ri.ModuleName) as 'Total risks'
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(varchar(7), r.CreatedDate, 126) as [month], a.AssociatedRisk, m.ModuleName
        FROM RiskTable r
        FULL OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT DISTINCT AssociatedRisk
            FROM RiskTable
        ) as a on a.AssociatedRisk IS NOT NULL
        FULL OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT DISTINCT ModuleName
            FROM RiskTable
        ) as m on m.ModuleName IS NOT NULL
        WHERE r.CreatedDate >= @start_date
    ) as ac
    LEFT JOIN RiskTable ri on ac.[month] = CONVERT(varchar(7), ri.CreatedDate, 126)
```